# Jquery not change style display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Clicking on  should stagnant display style in another , but it does not change, please help!

Can I make a different and more compact code?

HTML CODE:

```
                                    <tr onclick="NewToggleLayer('layer_{$ban_list.bid}')" style="background: #DBF4D7" class='list'>

<td class="_center"><img alt="{if $ban_list.mod == "html"}{"_WEB"|lang}{else}{$ban_list.mod|lang}{/if}" title="{if $ban_list.mod == "html"}{"_WEB"|lang}{else}{$ban_list.mod|lang}{/if}" src="images/games/{$ban_list.mod}.gif" /></td>
                                <td>{$ban_list.ban_created|date_format:"%Y-%m-%d"}</td>
                                <td><img alt="" src="images/country/{if $ban_list.cc}{$ban_list.cc|lower}{else}clear{/if}.png" /> {$ban_list.player_nick}</td>
                                <td>{$ban_list.admin_nick}</td>
                                <td>{$ban_list.ban_reason}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {if $ban_list.ban_length>0}
                                        {$ban_list.ban_length*60|date2word:true}
                                    {else}
                                        {"_PERMANENT"|lang}
                                    {/if}
                                </td>
                                {if $ban_page.show_comments == 1 && $vars.use_comment == 1}<td class="_center">{$ban_list.comment_count}</td>{/if}
                                {if $ban_page.show_demos == 1 && $vars.use_demo == 1}<td class="_center">{$ban_list.demo_count}</td>{/if}
                                {if $ban_page.show_kicks == 1}<td class="_center">{$ban_list.kick_count}</td>{/if}
                            </tr>

                            <tr id="layer_{$ban_list.bid}" style="display:none;">
        blah blah
            </td>
```

This is java function:

```
function ToggleLayer(obj) {
    if (document.all) {
        if (document.all[obj].style.display == 'none') {
            document.all[obj].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.all[obj].style.display = 'none';
        }
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById(obj).style.display == 'none') {
            if (document.getElementById(obj).tagName == 'DIV') {
                document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'table-row';
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
function NewToggleLayer(element) {
    var e = $('#' + element);
    if (e.css('display') == 'none') {
        e.show().find('div').slideDown('slow')
    } else {
        e.find('div').slideUp('slow', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        })
    }
} /* Version checker */
$(function () {
    var chkver = document.createElement("script");
    chkver.type = "text/javascript";
    chkver.async = true;
    chkver.src = "//version.gm-community.net/amxbans.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(chkver, s);
});

function setLastVersion(ver) {
    if (parseFloat($('#version').text()) < ver) {
        $('#version').addClass('MustUpdate').append('text');
    }
}
```

How to shorten the function and make smaller?

Comment: *"This is java function:"* No, this is a *JavaScript* function. Java != JavaScript

Comment: Look at your question for a moment, in particular the markup formatting and the code formatting. Clear? Easy to read?

Comment: Your JavaScript code are ... unreadable

Comment: Since this is about improving working code, I would suggest you fix the formatting in your question and post it on [codereview.se].

Comment: Hard to read it's true ! You should firstly use Jquery show() or hide() function to edit your display attribute (if you want to hide or show). Jquery .show() will automaticly set the right display attribute, according to the element.

Comment: You definitely should use indentation and format your code. This is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ToggleLayer(obj) {
    var $element = $(obj);
    $element.toggle(); // if hidden then will show otherwise hide 
                       // or $element.slideToggle();
}

function NewToggleLayer(element) {
    var e = $('#' + element);
    if (!e.is(':visible')) {
        e.show().find('div').slideDown('slow')
    } else {
        e.find('div').slideUp('slow', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        })
    }
}
```